# Reduce number of operators in an RxJS mapping expression

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I've create an Http request to get json data. Inside that json - there is an object which has an array. ( I need that array).

```
fromDb$ = of({
    Result: {
      Countries: [{      <--wanted array
        ISOCode: 1,
        Name: 'aaa'

      }, {
        ISOCode: 2,
        Name: 'bbb'

      }]
    }
  });
```

But- the data in  the array  has a different structure than I actually need.

I need to map (`name` &`ISOcode`) to (`name` and `value`  )

This is what I've tried:

- Use `pluck` to extract the inner Array
- `mergeMap` the array object to a stream of objects (using `of()`)
- using `map` to transform each item to a desired structure
- using `toArray` to wrap all to an array ( so I can bind it to a control)

Here is the actual code :

```
this.data = this.fromDb$.pipe(pluck<PtCountries, Array<Country>>('Result', 'Countries'), 
                                mergeMap(a => from(a)),
                                map((c: Country) => ({
                                  name: c.Name,
                                  value: c.ISOCode,
                                })),
                              toArray());
```

The code does work and [**here is the online demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-goqrxl?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Question**

It looks like I've complicated it much more than it can be ,Is there a better  way of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line: `mergeMap(a => from(a))` does not make a lot of sense. It's almost as if you did `[1,2,3].map(v => v)`. You can just remove it.

To simplify this you basically need to use Array.map inside Observable.map.

Try this:

```
this.data = this.fromDb$.pipe(pluck<PtCountries, Array<Country>>('Result', 'Countries'),
  map((countries: Country[]) => countries.map(country => ({
    name: country.Name,
    value: country.ISOCode,
}))));
```

[Live demo](https://stackoverflow-reduce-number-of-operators.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 0):

```
    this.data = this.fromDb$.pipe(
        mergeMap(object => object.Result.Countries),
        map(country => ({ name: country.Name, value: country.ISOCode })),
        toArray()
    );
```

Comment: I get errors can you please use the demo link above ?

Comment: Hmm, must be an issue with Typescript - my version with plain javascript worked. I'll look into it later.

Comment: OK, there was a problem with flatMap, which was changed to mergeMap apparently. I returned the toArray operator, although I think it is better to fill the this.data array in a subscription.